# How would i make a loop to find the smallest number in a list and sort smallest to biggest

Tags: python, sorting

```
input('Welcome! To the SECOND best Selection sort program EVER, press ENTER to continue: ')
nums = (input('Please enter your values: ')).split(' ')
```

I need to create an algorithm of loops that will sort numbers from a list smallest to biggest WITHOUT using pythons intergrated sorting function.

Comment: @Jab i dont know what im doing theres not much code i can provide thats why im asking the question

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

Comment: @DACHICKENWINGS did you read the link? Please do at least some research before asking here. And when asking provide enough info for us to be able to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). We're not going to do your homework for you, but if you get stuck, you can ask here. See also [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea this isnt homework this is a personal project actually, i would appreciate if you could get more info before jumping to conclusions i already know how to do it with the integrated function so i want to learn how to do without so i can get better with loops.

Comment: @DA OK, I assumed because in practice, there's usually no reason to implement your own sort method in Python. Anyway, since you're working in theory, a lot of the same advice applies as homework: start with your own research, try implementing it yourself before posting a question, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any sorting algorithms, like [mergesort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-merge-sort/) or even [insertion sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-insertion-sort/) as mergesort is one of the best sorting algorithms with a time complexity of **`O(nlog(n))`** in all the cases while insertion sort works well for lists with small sizes but becomes expensive if the size is large